# How do I avoid adding unrelated maven plugins to subprojects?

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a maven project `A` with a pluginManagement configuration for plugin `P`. I have a separate maven project `B` without a dependency on plugin `P`.  Project `A` is not a parent of project `B`. I have a third project `C` whose parent project is `A` that uses plugin P

```
A (pluginManagement P)
|- B
|- C (plugin P)
```

When I try to run a goal from plugin `P` on project `A`, maven tries to execute that goal project `B` as well, and fails.

> [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'P' in the current project
>   and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
>   available from the repositories [local] -> [Help 1]

However, if I add a plugin `P` to project `B`'s plugin dependencies, everything works.

```
A (pluginManagement P)
|- B (pluginManagement P)
|- C (plugin P)
```

Is there a way to avoid this dependency propagation? It seems like I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, there appear to be two Maven Ways to do this. For clarity, assume there is another project `D` that also uses plugin `P`, that plugin `P` is configured with configuration `PC`, and that plugin `P` has goal `G`.

Create an additional aggregator POM that doesn't have pluginManagement `P`, and aggregate project `B` under it

```
Alpha
|- A (pluginManagement P [PC])
   |- C (plugin P)
   |- D (plugin P)
|- B
```

Don't use pluginManagement `P` and hard code `P`'s configuration `PC` in projects that use it.

```
A
|- B
|- C (plugin P [PC])
|- D (plugin P [PC])
```

Creating a separate aggregator POM seems like the best solution. However, there is an even simpler solution for me that results in less churn. I can simply invoke the `P`'s goal directly on project `C` like so:

```
mvn -pl :C P:G
```

This gives the maven reactor visibility into my entire project structure without propagating the goal onto all modules of `A`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Use pluginManagement, not plugins, at the top level, and then put the plugin clause in place where you want it.
2. (or) Set inherited to false.

Comment: I'm already using `pluginManagement` at the top level. Setting `inherited` to `false` worked.